# Removing round corners from the button in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have following button markup in a single/multiple page jquerymobile page template.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" >About Us</a>
```

I need to disable the round corners of this button using the button option as given in the jquerymobile docs.

I have tried `$('a').buttonMarkup({ corners: "false" })` in every events such as pagebeforecreate, pageinit, pagecreate and mobileinit

I never got it working and have been struggling with it to make it for quite a long time. I dont want to use  data attribute data-corners="false" for now.

Please suggest any ideas

Comment: Could you add a part of you script code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work: `$('a').buttonMarkup({ corners: false })` note "false" should not be a string.

Anyway, if you want to make that the default behaviour, you could try something like:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){
    $.fn.buttonMarkup.defaults.corners=false;
});
```

that should work the same as having `data-corners="false"` on every button.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the JqueryMobile css in your css

Normal jqm

```
.ui-btn-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:                 1em /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
    -webkit-border-radius:              1em /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
    border-radius:                      13px /*{global-radii-buttons}*/;
}
```

In your css just add

```
.ui-btn-corner-all{-moz-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-radius: 0;border-radius: 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks mario. This approach works pretty fine. I was looking forward into details what may be correct method to do it using the javascript calls as per their docs

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('body *').removeClass('ui-btn-corner-all');
});
```

Make jquery selector more optimized. Take it as just an idea.