# How do I remove just one side of a button's rounded corners?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two links side by side with data-role="button". I did have it in a controlgroup, but I couldn't change the width to 100%. Since I removed them from the controlgroup, I can set the proper width, but I want the same appearance of the controlgroup where the buttons have rounded corners and are right next to each other.
How do I remove just one side of a buttons rounded corners?

Comment: I am talking about a controlgroup with data-type="horizontal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/4wd92/

Wrap a button in div so css can apply only to it:

```
<div id="custom-button-container">
    <input type="button" data-theme="a" value="Changed Button">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#custom-button-container .ui-btn-corner-all {
    border-radius: 0 1em 1em 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could post some code it would be great, but else try and look at these links, it sounds like they can help you :)

You can experiment with something like this.
test

else some reading i found, might hold some answers.

[Removing round corners from the button in jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886014/removing-round-corners-from-the-button-in-jquery-mobile)

[How to remove round corners in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463300/how-to-remove-round-corners-in-jquery-mobile)